# Getting RSSI of nRF51822 bluetooth

Tags: arm, bluetooth-lowenergy, keil

I am using Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) 4.0 nRF51822 by Nordic Semiconductor, and I want to make a project on indoor localization, so I need the [RSSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication) (Received Signal Strength Indication) of [BLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy).

Can anyone one help?

Comment: For some given value of "help", [yes](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/questions/scope:all/sort:relevance-desc/page:1/query:RSSI/). A more specific question would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you but a kit to Nordic they provide you some documentation. Among that documentation i found the code of an app for Android ( and IOS ) which get some parameters, UUID, Major, Minor and de RSSI. You should check that code in order to get RSSI. Good luck, and the app name is nRFBeacon, and I think it's in Google Play also, but you'll need the source to solve your problem.